# Xamarin UWP Debug Build works, but not Release ("No embeddedresource found" and .NET Native Toolchain)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

So I have now finished coding for my **Xamarin Application** and all works fine in the **Debug** builds. I've then tested the **Release** build on Android by Archiving and Signing the **APK**, and it works fine, but the problem comes in when trying to Build the **UWP Project** Package Files. If I try to start the program then I get the following Exception:

```
+       $exception  {Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresource found for AppPrescribe.App
   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType)
   at AppPrescribe.UWP.MainPage..ctor() in D:\Xamarin\P\AppPrescribe\AppPrescribe\AppPrescribe.UWP\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 26
   at AppPrescribe.UWP.AppPrescribe_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage() in D:\Xamarin\P\AppPrescribe\AppPrescribe\AppPrescribe.UWP\obj\x86\Release\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 255
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.Xamarin_Forms_Platform_UAP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
   at __Interop.ReverseComStubs.Stub_19(Object __this, Void** unsafe_returnValue__retval, IntPtr __methodPtr)}  Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException
```

I'm also returned to my **UWP Project**, inside the `MainPage.xaml.cs` file, and my cursor is placed next to `LoadApplication(new AppPrescribe.App());` inside the `MainPage` Constructor.

And if I try to go ahead with Creating the App Packages, the Application crashes multiple times during the Test phases. *(Again, I changed no code between Debug and Release)*

*What am I missing here?
Forgive me if it's a dumb solution.*

I've tried:

- removing and re-adding the reference to my .NET Class Library with
  the shared code, then do a Clean and Rebuild
- Deleted bin and obj files, do a Clean and Rebuild
- uninstalled Debug App and do Clean and Rebuild

but I still get the same error.

EDIT: If I **uncheck** "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" then the app compiles fine and **runs** in debug, but then I cannot create the App package because **Windows App Certification** fails the **Binary Analyzer** side of the *testing*. 
If I leave it checked (along with **Optimize Code**) and then debug, the Application goes into Break Mode and I get this **Exception**:

`Unhandled exception at 0x101F43FA (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in DisChemPrescribe.UWP.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x0352CD90, 0x00000002).`

Comment: Similar reports on images and resources in Xamarin->UWP were solved by changing the toolchain (using .Net native toolchain - can be set in the the Build properties of the project)

Comment: @auX It was already checked in the Build properties. I've now unchecked it and it seems to be working now when I debug. Although I'm guessing that's not exactly a good thing, deactivating the .NET Native Toolchain I mean.

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck  `Optimize Code` option in the debug model ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The Debug model has both of those unchecked by default, which I'm guessing is why the Debug model runs fine. If I uncheck these in the Release model, Windows App Certification gives a nice big red "Failed" rating when making the App Package, which can be bad if I want to submit to the Store. Are these bugs that Microsoft needs to fix?

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you update **PCL** projects into **.Net Standard**. If you open a PCL's csproj file you'll see Xaml and Xaml.cs connections like

```
</Compile>
    <Compile Include="OverviewPage.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Overview.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

However, once you migrate your **PCL** to **.Net Standard** this connections dissapears.

There are 2 solution to fix this issue (afaik).

**Add embedded resource definiton to csproj file**

```
  <EmbeddedResource Update="OverviewPage.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
  </EmbeddedResource>
```

**Use Xaml Compilations: Add Xaml compilation tag for all xaml.cs files**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I must tell you that when I created the project, I chose it to be .NET Standard Library and not PCL. (Seeing as Visual Studio doesn't give you the option to choose PCL when creating a Cross Platform Project anymore). But I did add `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` above all the classes that didn't have it. The only ones that didn't have it was MainPage.xaml.cs and App.xaml.cs in my .NET Standard Library.
I'm still getting errors